# ESRI Map Cache Errors at Release 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2

I recently posted this issue with esri.  Has anyone experienced this?:

We are experiencing brand new caching issues at 10.2.2. I am unable to either DELETE_TILES or RECREATE_ALL_TILES from an existing cache. The error we keep receiving is:

Line 30Output failure, error string = Error moving bundle Failed to cache extent: -9223211.962860 3087885.815688 -9079003.170544 3271103.291998 at scale 577790.55428899999.

The error occures when running RECREATE_ALL_TILES or DELETE_TILES operations of the Manage Map Cache Tiles (run as a tool or script) when run from a dedicated server gp cluster machine. Our clustered setup consists of a network file server storing our config, security and data-stores, as well as all server and system directories. Two servers serve as a mapCluster for map and image services, a single server in a gpCluster for caching and user-defined gp services, and a virtualized web server for the WebAdaptor.

This has occurred as of lastweek whether reading from the GIS SDE database OR from a data-store file gdb. All permissions for directory shares and folder and file security have been accounted for.

When the error occurs, the entire cache becomes corrupt, making any other caching operations in-operable (delete cache, delete tiles, etc). During the recreate, the bundlx file is being removed but the bundle file is not, thus not allowing the tool to overwrite thebundle from the admin-defined D:/arcgistemp folder(s) on the GP server.

Thus far, the only solution has been to kill the service, stop the site, and then remove the entire cache directory, restart the site, recreate both the service and the cache.

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: Are your servers on Linux or Windows?

Comment: did u fix that ?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is little bit old topic but if someone is still dealing with this problem it can help. I try lot of different solutions and only this worked for me.

The cache of the service was created by default using compact caching. First thing to do is to explode the cache to png format (from ArcCatalog: Manage Cache > Convert Cache Format). After conversion is completed RECREATE_ALL_TILES in the extent you need: -9223211.962860 3087885.815688 -9079003.170544 3271103.291998 at scale 577790.55428899999.

Maybe this is not a solution more workaround but that helped us.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the message: **Output failure, error string = Error moving bundle** when I trying to execute **RECREATE_ALL_TILES** from the existing cache.

But this only happens when the cache folder contains cache (.bundle) generated by different ArcGIS versions (i.e. 10.5.1 and 10.6). So I delete these cache folders and recreate caches at these levels, everything works fine.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this is still up here.  More than anything this turned out to be network and security related when we were on old Windows 2008 R2 physical servers, and before we federated with Portal.  Since June of 2018, we moved to virtual (VMware) host for ArcEnterprise (10.6 at the time on Windows Server 2016) this problem went away.  We are at ArcEnterprise 10.7.1 now on the same virtual host